# Set generated by all finite field operations.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I was stuck on a problem for a while, and I'd just like to clarify something.

Let $K$ be a field and $S$ a subset of $K$. **$S$ is not necessarily a field.**

Let $K'$ be the intersection of all subfields of $K$ which contain $S$. This is equivalent to $K'$ being the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $S$.

The thing that caused me trouble for a while was proving that $K'$ is the set of all elements of $K$ that can be obtained from elements of $S$ by a finite sequence of field operations.

My understanding is that $+$ and $\times$ are the operations of a field, so all I can do is perform repeated combinations of addition and multiplication.

The books says that $\{1\}$ generates $\mathbb Q$.

As far as I could tell: if $+$ and $\times$ are the only field operations then $\{1\}$ can only generate $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, which isn't even a field!

Am I right to assume that $-$ and $\div$ are field operations? If we allow $-$ and $\div$ then $\{1\}$ generates $\mathbb Q$.

My understanding was that subtraction was addition of the additive inverse: $x-y = x+(-y)$ and that division was multiplication by the multiplicative inverse: $x \div y = x \times y^{-1}$.

My worry was that $S$ was a subset, and not necessarily a field, so for any $x \in S$, it might not be true that $(-x) \in S$ or that $x^{-1} \in S$, and so do $x-y$ and $x\div y$ make sense?

**Edit**

I understand that $K'$ is supposed to the field of rational expressions $K(S)$, i.e. quotients of polynomials in elements of $S$. But I can't build that without division and subtraction.

Comment: You certainly don't have the _operations_ subtract and divide, but since every field _must_ contain additive and multiplicative inverses, as soon as you add $1$ with itself to get $2$, you 'automatically' get $-2$ and $2^{-1}$. If you didn't, you wouldn't have a field as you wouldn't satisfy all the axioms.

Comment: @BillWallis Thanks for the reply Bill. I don't see how we get $-2$ and $2^{-1}$ from ${1}$ when we're only allowed $+$ and $\times$. I have to start with an arbitrary subset (**not assumed to be a field**), and $K'$ is defined to be the set of all elements of K that can be obtained from elements of S by a finite sequence of field operations. This is somehow a field. (The author uses $\pm$ and division in his equations.):

$$\frac{\pm(1+1+\cdots+1)}{1+1+\cdots+1}$$

Comment: @BillWallis The confusion for me, and forgive me overwhelming stupidity, is the phrase "$K'$is the set of all elements of $K$ that can be obtained from elements of $S$ by a finite sequence of field operations." The confusion for me is that $x \mapsto -x$ and $y \mapsto y^{-1}$ are not field operations. For me, only $(x,y) \mapsto x \times y$ and $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ are field operations. If the definition of field operations includes $x \mapsto -x$ and $y \mapsto y^{-1}$ then I'm happy and all of my problems are solved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, the author of your book must have intended $-$ and $\div$ to be considered as field operations. Otherwise, the result that "$K'$ is the set of all elements that can be obtained from $K$ using a finite number of operations" would be false.

$x-y$ and $x\div y$ make sense in $K$, and $S$ is a subset of $K$, so they make sense in $S$. The result of the operation will not be in $S$, but that is not a problem; $-$ and $\div$ are not operations on $S$, they are operations on $K$.

Comment: That's great Mike, thank you very much. I get it now :-)